# Is that possible to use ArrayList<hashmap<String,String>> in ExpandabliListivew ChildRows?

Tags: android

I want to populate my `ExpandableListview` with a data from ArrayList> , but every time when I send this `ArrayList<hashmap<String,String>>` to the adapter it only returns the first item and repeats them for expample
when I add

```
ArrayList<hashmap<String,String>> child=new ArrayList<hashmap<String,String>>();

HashMap<String,String> hm=new HashMap<String,String>();

hm.put("Key1","Value1");
hm.put("Key2","Value2");
child.add(hm);
```

It creats two child rows with same data which are `Value1`

how to solve this? as I think `ArrayList<hashmap<String,String>>` couldnt be used for populating child rows in ExpandabliListview because it works for `ArrayList<String>` , if this possible please help me